# Django relations between Models

Tags: python, django

What I currently have in my models is this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=255, default='Agent')
```

Now my question is: Users should be able to have multiple Projects - so I obviously can't use a OneToOne-Field in the Profile-Model.

Later I want to use it for example to just show a user news which are only related to the projects he participates in.

What would be the best strategy to make this possible? Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, depending on the objective. You say users should be able to have multiple projects; should projects also have multiple users? If so, you can add a `ManyToManyField` on `Project`. If not, it should be a `ForeignKey`. 

If it's a `ManyToManyField`, it can be on either `Project` or `Profile`, but I think semantically it makes more sense on `Project`, linking it to the `User`, and not to the `Profile`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Interesting thoughts! The ManyToManyField is exactly what I needed. I will try to find out which link makes more sense on the later use to keep stuff as simple as possible. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ManyToMany on project.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=255, default='Agent')
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
```

This way one profile can have as many project as he/she wants

On your view you can use this field to filter based on project

Comment: Thank you very much, you removed the knot that was inside my brain. ;)

Just to make it complete: 
     project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

Comment: @Tobi right! I just fixed the code.... if that answer your question, consider accepting the answer :)